# Liferay roles not persisting

Tags: java, liferay, portlet

I have a login hook in liferay 6.1 that I have code in for assigning user roles on login. The code is:

```
 try{

            Company company = CompanyLocalServiceUtil.getCompanyByMx(PropsUtil.get(PropsKeys.COMPANY_DEFAULT_WEB_ID));         

            Long roleID = new Long(RoleLocalServiceUtil.getRole(company.getCompanyId(), "CurrentStudent-LP-229").getRoleId());
            System.out.println("Role ID: " + roleID.toString());
            long[] roleArray = new long[10];
            roleArray[0]=roleID;

            System.out.println(roleArray[0]);
            System.out.println("Got the role array");

            RoleLocalServiceUtil.addUserRoles(user.getUserId(), roleArray);

            System.out.println("added users roles");
            UserLocalServiceUtil.updateUser(user);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Problem setting roles: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

It runs all the way through and no exceptions are caught. All of my "success" flags that you see in the code print, but when I go into the liferay portal, my roles have not been updated. I expected it to either overwrite my roles or add it to my list of existing roles. Is there something I'm missing? Do I have to do something within the liferay control panel to be able to set roles? I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: This code will work only if your Custom Role is of type 'Regular'. Is your custom role "CurrentStudent-LP-229" is of regular type?

Comment: yes. they are all set to regular.